# Registrarse en firebase , guardando el nombre de usuario

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

necesito poder almacenar el nombre de usuario en firebase, ya que el "displayName" aparece como nulo, y al registrarme solo tengo el email y contraseña. Cuando intento utilizar el updateProfile, no se como pasarle las variables ingresadas en los inputs, ya tengo el inicio de sesion, y el registrar un nuevo usuario, lo unico que me falta es poder actualizar los demas datos del usuario

Comment: Comparte tu código para ver como te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Utiliza `Firebase Auth` para ese proposito, es muy sencillo de usar, brutalmente sencillo, no se si ya lo estas usando, pero por como lo describes parece que simplemente estas usando registros propios en una BD de firebase